# Как подключить h2-консоль в spring-webmvc без spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, h2, spring-jdbc

Приложение работает на `spring-webmvc` и `spring-jdbc` без `spring-boot`. В настройках `application.properties` указано следующее:

```ini
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

datasource.dbname=users
datasource.script=classpath:resources/users.sql
```

Но оно не запускает `h2-console`, потому что у меня не используются `spring-boot-devtools`, но нужны ли они мне? Поэтому я добавил бин [Server](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html) из пакета `org.h2.tools` следующим образом:

```java
// The web server is a simple standalone HTTP server that
// implements the H2 Console application.  localhost:8082
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server h2Server() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createWebServer();
}
```

Теперь я могу открыть web-консоль `localhost:8082` и подключиться к базе `jdbc:h2:mem:users`, только по-моему, это не решение, а обход проблемы, т.к. бин `DataSource` я подключаю с помощью [`EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder.html) следующим образом:

```java
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(
        @Value("${datasource.dbname}") String dbname,
        @Value("${datasource.script}") String script) {

    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .setName(dbname)
            .addScript(script)
            .build();
}
```

```java
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Есть ли какой-либо *спринговый способ* подключения `h2-console` в `spring-webmvc` без `spring-boot`? Или это нормально - подключать её таким образом?

**pom.xml**:

```xml
<!-- spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- h2 database -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
</dependency>

<!-- servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64488131/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

См справку - H2 Tutorial [Using the H2 Console Servlet](https://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#usingH2ConsoleServlet):

> The H2 Console is a standalone application and includes its own web server, but it can be used as a servlet as well. To do that, include the `h2*.jar` file in your application, and add the following configuration to your `web.xml`:
>
> ```xml
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.h2.server.web.WebServlet</servlet-class>
>     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
> </servlet>
> <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>H2Console</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/console/*</url-pattern>
> </servlet-mapping>
> ```

т. е. вместо сервера целиком, можно подключить к приложению только один сервлет, а *спринговый способ* может выглядеть примерно так:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
        . . .

        servletContext
                .addServlet("H2Console", WebServlet.class)
                .addMapping("/console/*");

        . . .
    }
}
```

Теперь можно подключаться к web-консоли как обычно `http://localhost:8080/console`